# Is it possible to query Office 365 Enterprise Audit Logs programmatically using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is there a way to query Office 365 Enterprise Audit Logs programmatically using Microsoft Graph / Client.  It is possible to manually query them in O365 Security & Compliance Center Page. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c

I am specifically interested in audit logs that contains file uploaded to OneDrive, or file opened /modified events from users within the tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Office 365 Management Activity API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)

The Office 365 Management Activity API aggregates actions and events into tenant-specific content blobs, which are classified by the type and source of the content they contain. Currently, these content types are supported:

Audit.AzureActiveDirectory

Audit.Exchange

Audit.SharePoint

Audit.General (includes all other workloads not included in the previous content types)

DLP.All (DLP events only for all workloads)

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is useful. Since my questions was about Microsoft Graph though, do you also know whether it is possible to access the O365 Activity Logs through Microsoft Graph. I would detest to maintain 2 separate frameworks and potentially multiple different authentication flows.. I am going to use MS Graph for accessing OneDrive and Sharepoint, AAD v2 and Microsoft App Registration Portal. If MS Graph currently does not expose Activity Logs, is it at least on the roadmap ?